# using pandas two perform Cross tab between one column and two others that share the same enumerated values

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have table with

```
|Majors|First Minor|Second Minor|
|Philosophy|English|Null|
|Math|Philosophy|English|
|English|Theology|Political Science
|Philosophy|Theology|English|
```

The possible values of the "First Minor" and "Second Minor" columns are the same (English, Philosophy, Math, etc)

I want to see the correlation between "Major" and the "Minors" belonging to those majors. I don't care if the minor is a first or second minor. So based on the above sample I want an output that looks something like:

```
|Major|Philosophy|Math|English
First Minor||||     
Philosophy|0|1|0|
|Math|0|0|0|
|English|2|1|0|
Political Science|0|0|1|
Theology|1|0|1|
Null|1|0|0
```

The following code generates the desired result for just the "First Minor" or the "Second Minor":

`ct = pd.crosstab(newdf.MajorInterMinor, newdf["First Minor"])`

But I want to get the results for both columns ("First Minor" and "Second Minor") and I can't figure out how to get the combined result.

Any help/advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the Minors, then apply `crosstab`:

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars='Majors', value_name='Minors')

pd.crosstab(df2['Majors'], df2['Minors'])
```

Output:

```
Minors      English  Null  Philosophy  Political Science  Theology
Majors                                                            
English           0     0           0                  1         1
Math              1     0           1                  0         0
Philosophy        2     1           0                  0         1
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know about melt. I had to change it just a bit to: `df2 = newdf.melt(id_vars="Majors", value_vars=["First Minor", "Second Minor"])` and then I ran the cross tab as follows: `crosstabresult = pd.crosstab(df2.Majors, df2["value"])

Answer (score 1):

pd.melt to collapse `FirstMinor`, `SecondMinor` into one column and make new df

```
 df2 = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Majors'], value_vars=['FirstMinor','SecondMinor'],var_name='myVarname', value_name='FirstMinor_SecondMinor')
```

Slice new df to  get_dummies on Majors. Join this back to the df. Groupby and sum

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.loc[:,'FirstMinor_SecondMinor']).join(pd.get_dummies(df2.loc[:,'Majors'])).groupby('FirstMinor_SecondMinor').agg(sum)

   

                          English  Math  Philosophy
FirstMinor_SecondMinor                           
English                       0     1           2
Null                          0     0           1
Philosophy                    0     1           0
PoliticalScience              1     0           0
Theology                      1     0           1
```

Comment: do I need to do the `get_dummies` stuff? After doing the melt as follows: `df2 = newdf.melt(id_vars="Majors", value_vars=["First Minor", "Second Minor"])`, the following seemed to work: `crosstabresult = pd.crosstab(df2.Majors, df2["value"])`

Comment: You are right, crosstab should still work. Just provided alternative approach